# How do I implement a Background process in gunicorn?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, gunicorn

I am developing my own VPN server and faced a problem that I do not understand. My bot consists of two microservices: one is responsible for the telegram webapp, the other for interacting with the VPN and the database. I use gunicorn + Flask as a stack. On the server side, I run 2 more background processes: the first is responsible for interacting with the bot using commands, the second is responsible for the daily withdrawal of funds. Below is an example of the code:

```py
def preload():
    logging.basicConfig(filename="app.log",
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
                        filemode="w")
    
    logging.info('Start wolfvpn')
    print(f'PID = {os.getpid()}, time = {time.time()}')
    
    p = mp.Process(target=debit.auto_daily_debit, daemon=True)
    p.start()  # daily withdrawal

    bot_run_p = mp.Process(target=bot.main, daemon=True)
    bot_run_p.start()  # bot commands

    Connection.db = DataBaseManager(db_config['dbname'], db_config['user'], db_config['password'])
    CreateTable().execute()
```

But at launch, I found that at some point the process with the database is destroyed and a new one is created, because of this, funds are debited twice. I thought there was a memory overflow, but that's not it.

Below is an example of a log of who the work was first on one process, then continued on another and returned again to the first

```bash
2023-12-11 00:12:56,481 INFO new user balance/ User=1480477773, amount=714, PID = 34
2023-12-11 00:12:56,482 INFO update user balance/ User=708133213, amount=0, PID = 34
2023-12-11 00:12:56,483 INFO update user balance/ User=1938363162, amount=20, PID = 34
2023-12-11 00:12:56,483 INFO update user balance/ User=6659705625, amount=0, PID = 34
2023-12-11 11:01:16,965 ERROR Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected
2022023-12-12 00:11:56,547 INFO update user balance/ User=891152952, amount=0, PID = 27
2023-12-12 00:11:56,549 INFO update user balance/ User=415593670, amount=26, PID = 27
2023-12-12 00:11:56,550 INFO update user balance/ User=415986100, amount=0, PID = 27
2023-12-12 00:11:56,551 INFO update user balance/ User=795927427, amount=0, PID = 27
2023-12-12 00:11:56,551 INFO update user balance/ User=340996859, amount=8, PID = 27
2023-12-12 00:11:56,552 INFO update user balance/ User=879326192, amount=8, PID = 27
2023-12-12 00:11:56,553 2023-12-12 00:13:02,378 INFO update user balance/ User=891152952, amount=0, PID = 34
2023-12-12 00:13:02,379 INFO update user balance/ User=415593670, amount=26, PID = 34
2023-12-12 00:13:02,380 INFO update user balance/ User=415986100, amount=0, PID = 34
```

And actually the question is how to properly configure the database connection so that it runs only in one gunicorn process? And perhaps there are more correct approaches to solving this problem? I am a student, so there is no one to ask, who is like the forum participants)

Comment: Can you post your config gunicorn?,

Comment: @TanThien I did not find a normal article with a clear explanation of writing the gunicorn configuration, but I run with the following parameters: 

`gunicorn --certfile ssl.crt --keyfile ssl.key -b 0.0.0.0:8443 --workers 1 wsgi:app --preload` 

my wsgi file looks like this
`from app import app, preload \n
preload()`

During this time, I looked at the processes inside the docker container. For some reason, the gunicorn control process creates 3 child processes for connecting the database and one for my flask application, in which it also creates another child process.